# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: mpi/MPIException

Tags: java, openmpi

I want to use open-mpi for java.
I got the last version of open-mpi here https://www.open-mpi.org/software/ompi/v4.1/
Then install it using the next commands:

sudo ./configure --prefix=/Users/user/openmpi --disable-mpi-fortran --disable-mpi-cxx --disable-mpi-cxx-seek --disable-openib-dynamic-sl --disable-openib-connectx-xrc --disable-openib-udcm --disable-openib-rdmacm --disable-vt --disable-libompitrace --without-slurm --without-lsf --without-tm --without-ugni --without-mx --enable-mpi-java --with-jdk-dir=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.12.jdk/Contents/Home/ --with-threads=posix 2>&1 | tee config.out
sudo make -j 4 2>&1 | tee make.out
sudo make install 2>&1 | tee install.out

So, there is mpi.jar in /Users/user/openmpi/lib

I need to launch a test project from my teacher https://bitbucket.org/mathpar/dap/

I added mpi.jar to Dependencies in Intellij Idea. Set up $PATH with /Users/user/openmpi/bin

After building the project, I wanna run example target/classes/com/mathpar/NAUKMA/examples/HelloWorldParallel
Here is command: mpirun -np 1 java -cp /Users/user/IdeaProjects/dap/target/classes com/mathpar/NAUKMA/examples/HelloWorldParallel

I got: Error: Unable to initialize main class com.mathpar.NAUKMA.examples.HelloWorldParallel
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: mpi/MPIException

I was trying to change either of params (-cp Classpath or path to file), but I got e.g.: Error: Could not find or load main class com.mathpar.NAUKMA.examples.HelloWorldParallel.java
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mathpar.NAUKMA.examples.HelloWorldParallel.java

So I think that problem not in paths

If you need more information, you are welcome

Here is com.mathpar.NAUKMA.examples.HelloWorldParallel:

```
package com.mathpar.NAUKMA.examples;

import mpi.*;

public class HelloWorldParallel {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws MPIException {
        //iнiцiалiзацiя паралельної частини
        MPI.Init(args);
        //визначення номера процесора
        int myrank = MPI.COMM_WORLD.getRank();
        System.out.println("Proc num " + myrank + " Hello World");
        //завершення паралельної частини
        MPI.Finalize();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try:
mpirun -np 1 java -cp /Users/user/dap/target/classes com/mathpar/NAUKMA/examples/HelloWorldParallel

Answer (score 0):

It works for me:

Users/!!user!!/openmpi/bin/mpirun --hostfile  /Users/!!user!!/dap/hostfile -np 8 java -cp  /Users/!!user!!/dap/target/classes com/mathpar/NAUKMA/examples/HelloWorldParallel